# I am doing the raytracer in a week and i only render the first row.How can i fix it?

Tags: rust, raytracing

I don't understand what the problem is even though I looked through the code several times, but because I am new I might be missing something very important.Rust is a bit quirky.

```
fn main() {
    const HEIGHT:i32= 256;
    const WIDHT:i32 = 256;

    println!("P3\n{} {}\n255",WIDHT,HEIGHT);

    let mut i_count=HEIGHT-1;
    let mut n_count=0;

    while i_count >= 0
    {
        while n_count <=WIDHT-1
        {
            let r = n_count as f64 / (WIDHT-1)as f64;
            let g = i_count as f64 / (HEIGHT-1)as f64;
            let b =0.25;

            let ir = (255.999*r)as i64;
            let ig = (255.999*g)as i64;
            let ib = (255.999*b)as i64;

            println!("{} {} {}",ir,ig,ib);
            n_count=n_count+1;
        }
        i_count=i_count-1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community Bot being weird :D for reference, it's supposed to produce a [ppm image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm#PPM_example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not initialize `ncount` back to zero. After the first loop, `ncount` is always equal to `WIDHT` (256), skipping the inner loop body. You should learn to step through your code in a debugger, which will allow you to see the variables at any point.

```
fn main() {
    const HEIGHT:i32= 256;
    const WIDHT:i32 = 256;

    println!("P3\n{} {}\n255",WIDHT,HEIGHT);

    let mut i_count=HEIGHT-1;
    let mut n_count=0;

    while i_count >= 0
    {
        n_count = 0;
        while n_count <=WIDHT-1
        {
            let r = n_count as f64 / (WIDHT-1)as f64;
            let g = i_count as f64 / (HEIGHT-1)as f64;
            let b =0.25;

            let ir = (255.999*r)as i64;
            let ig = (255.999*g)as i64;
            let ib = (255.999*b)as i64;

            println!("{} {} {}",ir,ig,ib);
            n_count=n_count+1;
        }
        i_count=i_count-1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd almost argue that if this style of loop is used, the `let mut n_count` should be inside if the first loop. There is no reason to reuse it between iterations.

Answer (score 2):

What @Dark said.

As an additional remark, the exact problem you ran into is the reason why this kind of loop is discouraged (not just in Rust, but in general). If you want to iterate through a range, use range iterators instead. They are much less error prone.

```rust
fn main() {
    const HEIGHT: i32 = 256;
    const WIDTH: i32 = 256;

    println!("P3\n{} {}\n255", WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    for i_count in (0..HEIGHT).rev() {
        for n_count in 0..WIDTH {
            let r = n_count as f64 / (WIDTH - 1) as f64;
            let g = i_count as f64 / (HEIGHT - 1) as f64;
            let b = 0.25;

            let ir = (255.999 * r) as i64;
            let ig = (255.999 * g) as i64;
            let ib = (255.999 * b) as i64;

            println!("{} {} {}", ir, ig, ib);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well i couldn't get ranges and for loops working right. Again a beginner mistake.

Comment: No problem. Welcome to the community :) we are here to help.